# Push Notifications are not received sometimes

Tags: ios, push-notification, sandbox

I have this strange problem with **iOS Push Notifications:**

I configured my server to send push notifications, yet sometimes they are not delivered.

In order to get them back to work on a specific device, I have to turn OFF the Wi-Fi and switch it back ON. After that the message is received.

I'm still trying to put my finger on that issue, without luck.

**More Info:**

1.Server is working in sandbox mode.

2.Development certificates are in use.

3.Other notifications still works while mine won't (Facebook, Whatsapp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my theory, there are some differences between test APNS server, and real APNS server.

I do not think that is your problem.

Log something after send a message to APNS server

Comment: hi Oh Seung Kwon, I tried using Wireshark to listen to the send-push process, and it was OK. (the message was delivered to the APNS server)

Comment: I think it is absolutely not your problem.

Comment: I think test APNS is worse than the real one or traffic goes more than

Answer (score 0):

Try to take off the sandbox and set it to false.

Check your certificates.. if you have ad hoc certificate, notifications will only work when you create an IPA and install it on your device. Or if you download the app from the applestore.

Another issue can may cause your problem is the Data traffic.
If your phone does not have internet unless it connects to wifi, the device doesn't recive the push notification until it is not connected to wifi.

Hope it helps.